# How is ORB distinct from an endpoint?

Tags: java, enterprise-architecture, java-ee, distributed-computing, enterprise-development

What, fundamentally, am I misunderstanding about how to use `appclient`?

> The Application Client Container (ACC) includes a set of Java classes,
>   libraries, and other files that are required for and distributed with
>   Java client programs that execute in their own Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM). The ACC manages the execution of Java EE application client
>   components (application clients), which are used to access a variety
>   of Java EE services (such as JMS resources, EJB components, web
>   services, security, and so on.) from a JVM outside the Oracle
>   GlassFish Server. The ACC communicates with the GlassFish Server using
>   RMI-IIOP protocol and manages the details of RMI-IIOP communication
>   using the client ORB that is bundled with it. Compared to other Java
>   EE containers, the ACC is lightweight.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
Application Development Guide
Release 4.0
Developing Java Clients 10-16

But there's a gap in explaining how to do that from a **host** versus from directly on the **ORB**.  Or is that not even the correct terminology?  In this case there are two ORB's?  ORB to ORB over IIOP?

I'm trying to understand how to run a [client hello world](https://github.com/THUFIR/GreeterCorbaClient) program with appclient, and the terminology and concepts involved.  I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of the technologies, or am reading the manuals incorrectly.

The ORB, broker is on `doge`@192.168.1.2, and running the JAR directly on the same machine as the ORB works fine:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ appclient -client  NetBeansProjects/corba/GreeterCorbaClient/dist/GreeterCorbaClient.jar 
{org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.1.2, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1}
[fred, flinstone, barney, rubble, wilma]
thufir@doge:~$
```

The "host" is the remote machine?  The remote machine is `tleilax`@192.168.1.3 and should connect to the ORB, `doge`.

The fine manual:

> Example 1 Using the appclient command

```
appclient -xml sun-acc.xml -jar myclientapp.jar scott sample
```

> Where: sun-acc.xml is the name of the client configuration XML file,
>   myclientapp.jar is the client application .jar file, and scott and
>   sample are arguments to pass to the application. If sun-acc.xml and
>   myclientapp.jar are not in the current directory, you must give the
>   absolute path locations; otherwise the relative paths are used. The
>   relative path is relative to the directory where the command is being
>   executed.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
Reference Manual
Release 4.0
p. 704

appclient -help says:

```
   -targetserver
       optional; a comma-separated list of one or more server
       specifications for ORB endpoints. Each server specification must
       include at least the host. Optionally, a server specification can
       include the port as well. If the port is omitted from a server
       specification, the default value, 3700, is used for that host.
```

I don't understand the terminology involved, apparently.

What **parameters** do I pass appclient, and **how** do I pass those parameters, for a **remote** application?

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ appclient -targetserver 192.168.1.2:3700  -jar GreeterCorbaClient.jar 
{org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=192.168.1.2, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1}
```

The host, `tleilax`@192.168.1.3, connects to `doge`@192.168.1.2 fine:

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ telnet 192.168.1.2 3700
Trying 192.168.1.2...
Connected to 192.168.1.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
^C
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
thufir@tleilax:~$
```

If I **include the host** when running the app **from the host** I get the promising output:

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ appclient -targetserver 192.168.1.3,192.168.1.2:3700  -jar GreeterCorbaClient.jar 
Mar 13, 2015 5:50:33 AM org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager getCorbalocURL
INFO: list[i] ==> 192.168.1.3:3700
Mar 13, 2015 5:50:33 AM org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager getCorbalocURL
INFO: list[i] ==> 192.168.1.2:3700
Mar 13, 2015 5:50:33 AM org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager getCorbalocURL
INFO: corbaloc url ==> iiop:1.2@192.168.1.3:3700,iiop:1.2@192.168.1.2:3700
```

but then it hangs.

What is happening?  I'm at a loss. The glassfish log shows:

```
[2015-03-13T04:30:00.695-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1426246200695] [levelValue: 800] [[
  SimpleGreeterEAR was successfully deployed in 4,470 milliseconds.]]

[2015-03-13T04:31:38.082-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=PingService] [timeMillis: 1426246298082] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Domain Pinged: release.glassfish.org]]
```

which sounds good, a ping.

How do I troubleshoot this?  I could read CORBA manuals till the end of time, or every page of every Glassfish manual, but I don't know that this would help *much*.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution per se.  I must have some sort of misunderstanding of the concepts involved. It's more a design or methodology question than "solution" per se.